# Postgresql update tstzrange is not updating record in db

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have query like this

```
UPDATE "reservations" 
  SET "range" = tstzrange('2022-01-01T14:00:00.000Z', '2022-01-10T20:10:55.000Z', '(]') 
WHERE "id" = 'some_id'
```

and when I execute it (I enter different dates than in current record in db) sometimes record is updated and sometimes not.

I mean when I change dates e .g to

```
tstzrange('2022-01-01T16:00:00.000Z', '2022-01-10T20:10:00.000Z', '(]')
tstzrange('2022-01-01T12:00:00.000Z', '2022-01-10T15:10:00.000Z', '(]')
tstzrange('2022-01-10T16:00:00.000Z', '2022-01-20T20:10:00.000Z', '(]')
```

the result shows sometimes that record was updated and sometimes not.
I do not understand why record is not updating (I always change date to different than is current set.

Comment: can you provide a dbfiddle with concrete example, where it doesn't update, it seems unlikely

Comment: Do you get a feedback that one row was updated, but the value didn't change? Or do you get the feedback that your UPDATE did not change any rows?

Comment: Either this condition `WHERE "id" = 'some_id'` is not being met or you are not always committing the transaction.